# Distance formula between two Lat/Longs Autoit?

Tags: trigonometry, autoit

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two coordinates and I'm having trouble. I've seen formulas for JavaScript but can't seem to convert it to Autoit correctly. Example

```
$lat1 = 34.521630
$lon1 = -119.134680

$lat2 = 34.911463
$lon2 = -119.453130

;
;
;  $distance = Some code here that will calculate distance
;
;
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a question of AutoIt itself, you need the right algorithm:

```
#include <Math.au3>

$lat1 = 34.521630
$lon1 = -119.134680

$lat2 = 34.911463
$lon2 = -119.453130

ConsoleWrite(_distanceInKm($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) & @CRLF)

Func _distanceInKm($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2)
    Local $iRadius = 6371

    Local $iLat = _Radian($lat2 - $lat1)
    Local $iLon = _Radian($lon2- $lon1)

    Local $a = Sin($iLat / 2) * Sin($iLat / 2) + Cos(_Radian($lat1)) * Cos(_Radian($lat2)) * Sin($iLon / 2) * Sin($iLon / 2)
    Local $c = 2 * ATan2(Sqrt($a), Sqrt(1 - $a))
    Local $d = $iRadius * $c

    Return Abs($d)
EndFunc

Func ATan2($y, $x)
    Return (2 * ATan($y / ($x + Sqrt($x * $x + $y * $y))))
EndFunc
```